# Identifying a physical training device (pictures of a vertical padded tube with horizontal pipes coming out)

Tags: exercise

As you can see below, the physical training device consists of a thick padded central element, with padded poles sticking out of it, at multiple levels, hip and shoulder height. As for technique, one stands between the poles basically hitting them and the central element with the arms while dodging around them. They don't seem to spin, but I may be mistaken.

So the question is, what is it?

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 3]
[image: Image 4]
[image: Image 5]

Comment: That's the **Wing Chun** martial arts training dummy.

Comment: That is a variant of a wing chun training dummy. I flagged the question for migration to martial arts, you will get some good responses from the WC practitioners there.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like a modified blend of a [mu ren zhuang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mu_ren_zhuang), also known as a wooden training dummy. Different martial arts styles use them in different ways. The central padding aspect seems like it turns it into a punching bag of sorts.

Not sure how many people train in tight leather at night with shades on.

Comment: That's from **The Arrow** tv show :p

Comment: @Kneel-Before-ZOD It looks very control-oriented, though, which is something I haven't found good MMA exercises for. Trying one of these could be interesting.

Comment: @TheEnvironmentalist Read more about the Wing Chun fighting style *(hint: it's a close range fighting style)* and you'll understand the usage of this tool :).

Answer (score 3):

That's a wing chun dummy, modified with more padding.  Historically, they might have either no padding or a canvas bag of sand or beans attached as the target to practice hitting.

[This article covers the range of history of these devices](http://chinesemartialstudies.com/2012/08/24/traditional-training-equipment-in-the-chinese-martial-arts-part-ii-attack-of-the-wooden-dummies/), from simple striking poles to the more complex types of wooden dummies.  [This one covers specifically the evolution of the wing chun style striking dummy](http://chinesemartialstudies.com/2013/06/24/the-story-of-ip-mans-wooden-dummy/).

The typical use of these is that the arms simulate the height and distance of various guard positions or short range punches/strikes - you practice either deflecting or snaking around the positions to either strike or parry off an attack.  You can use it to build strength in applying deflection movements or grabs or build pain resistance to hard strikes by slamming it harder with your forearms.

Here's a video of a [slowed down wing chun form](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bqfPps556-A) using a dummy.  [Here's Donnie Yen demonstrating on a dummy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-KJFtLq0VWI) - watch how he angles to one side or the other as part of the practice.  [Here's an example of working with a "compact dummy"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZsO_iLALaio) - a board with arms you attach to the wall.

Answer (score 1):

This is variation of Wing Chun wooden dummy "muk yan jong\mu ren zhuang". Wing Chun uses dummy to train proper positions, control of you attacks as well as to simulate and to get used to involuntary reactions your opponent would have. If you deside to buy one I suggest caution. It is realy easy to hurt yourself if you don't know what you are doing.